# Xml layout changes while changing orientation

Tags: android, xml, layout, orientation

I have two activities which opens depending on the `SD` card presence. One activity has three `Buttons` and a `TextView` and the other an `ImageView`, a button and zoom control. When I change the orientation, the buttons get scrambled around while in horizontal direction. How to go around this?

> My 'SD' card layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#1E1E1E"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_print"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
        android:background="@drawable/my_button"
        android:text="@string/print" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_SDmissing"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:text="@string/SDmissing"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_camera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_print"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="58dp"
        android:background="@drawable/my_button"
        android:text="@string/camera" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_insert"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_SDmissing"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/my_button"
        android:text="@string/insert" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please show us your layout xml file(s).

Comment: pls post your xml file. If you need to change the layout based on orientation you have to give set two layout for layout-port and layout-land.

Comment: Have you tried providing different layouts for portrait/landscape?

Comment: how to do that? and will both have the exact copy or will it vary???

Answer (score 13):

You have to create separate XML files for portrait and landscape modes and place it in different directories. The device will automatically select the right one. You can use the following directory structure

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml   
res/layout-land/layout.xml
```

For further reference you can check:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: fine :) another question of mine is how to use a layout to support different screen sizes.....what  i am doing is that each time i rearrange and run the app and checking in my device but its not the same if i run the same in different app.....

Comment: Both file names must be same.

Answer (score 7):

You can make a folder in your project called "layout-land" (in the "res" directory). In there you can copy all your xml styles from the normal "layout" folder and restyle them for landscape mode. Android will automatically use those layouts for landscape mode.

Your project would look like this:

[image]