# How can I set separate splash screens for landscape and portrait mode in Android?

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

I'm working on an Android application where I need to set separate splash screens, one for portrait and one for landscape orientation. Both are different images. How can I do it?

**activity_splash.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/wwe_logo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**SplashScreen.java**

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    // Splash screen timer
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            /*
             * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
             * want to show case your app logo / company
             */

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                // Start your app main activity
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xml layout changes while changing orientation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630952/xml-layout-changes-while-changing-orientation)

Comment: It's Working .. Thank you soo much .. Answare  marked :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make 2 different layout with same file name and put the landscape layout in layout-land and the portrait in the default layout 
then no need to handle anything from java class

Answer (score 0):

If two layouts is not switching automatically after making `layout` and `layout-land` then you can do manually in `onCreate` before using `setContentView`

```
 if (this.getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                    .getOrientation() == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
               setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_portrait)
            } else {
               setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_land)
            }
```

Comment: there is a proper way to handle this using XML layout files and folder-naming in `/res/`.

Comment: Thanks bro, I thought that he knew about creating different XML for landscape and portrait orientation, And he didn't get the layout automatically.. So I've added alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps.

1. Create folder layout-land under res folder the same as the layout folder.
2. Next copy the activity_splash.xml file and paste in new folder layout-land. (This activity_splash is an XML file of SplashActivity java class)
3. Then change the portrait splash image to your landscape splash image.
   No need to change the java code in SplashActivity java class additionally also Manifest file.