# Android: How to separate screen into two fixed areas, in either orientation, and rotate content only within each area

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to create an app that divides the screen into two squarish halves; in either orientation.  The content within each half should rotate; but the two areas should remain fixed.

[image: layout diagram]

Could you tell me how to achieve this layout?  I would like to place an embedded browser in one half, and a QR code scanner in the other.

I imagine this is a noobish question; I've done very little android development.

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698817/linear-layout-and-weight-in-android

Comment: you have to create two different layouts to achieve this,when the screen rotates the layout will change according to your requirement ..see link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630952/xml-layout-changes-while-changing-orientation

Comment: did you use layout weight sum for this.

Comment: @NarendraBaratam and Mohamad: Thanks guys; a combination of your solutions worked for me.  I needed two layouts; Mohamad's Vertical and Horizontal layouts.    With the Horizontal layout in a layout-land folder.

Answer (score 0):

set `layout_weight` to `1` in both `LinearLayout` will divide the screen equally.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Main"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#9561A7"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!--views of the first section-->
        />

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#006C91" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!--views of the second section-->
      />
</LinearLayout>
```

good luck .

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't seem to behave as you describe http://mockupserver.com/images/notworking.png

Comment: yes my bad , you can change it from `android:orientation="horizontal"` to `vertical` , its not a good practice anyway.

Comment: Thanks again but now I have the opposite issue: http://mockupserver.com/images/notworking2.png

Answer (score 0):

you can use layout weight sum and layout weight for this purpose.

use to following line of code:

```
      <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/head"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"> 

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"> 

       </LinearLayout>
```